# Ajax Post text input

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I am attempting to submit the text input and have the page refresh with the submitted results, using Django for server-side. I am still very new to this. Am I doing this correctly?

Python/Django:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('qanda.views',
     url(r'^(?P<url_id>\d+)/(?P<link_id>\d+)/add_answer/$', 'add_answer')
```

jQuery:

```
$('#submitAnswer').on('click', function(e){
    var dataString = tinyMCE.get('addAnswer').getContent(); 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/add_answer",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            alert(dataString);
        }
    });
});
```

It would be great if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want the page to refresh, just don't use ajax and stop the form submission

Comment: What happened when you tried this code, and what did you expect?

Comment: Expected the text entered to appear after submitting. Nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a javascript debugger to see the ajax responses. You'd see you're getting a 404.

Your `url` does not match your django view..

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/add_answer",
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^ should be /1/1/add_answer/ 
            // (if this script is at /1/1/ remove the leading slash)

        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            alert(dataString);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where are you finding this Yuji? I don't see 404 error in firebug

Comment: I don't actually see it... but the URL you are posting to is an *absolute url* which does not match the django URL (it requires 2 parameters preceding the `add_answer` bit) thus you *should* be getting a 404, unless something else is listening at `/add_answer` in your django app.

Comment: Now I am getting a 403 forbidden error. Any idea why? If I go to the url directly it posts, but through ajax its giving me the error.

Comment: The error message would tell you that you're missing a CSRF token, so you'll need to add the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` to your ajax request, or disable csrf on this view.